# Finding the dimension and kernel of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I am working on solving this below problem:

> Let $F$ be a field, $n$ a natural number, and $T: F^n \to F^n$ a linear map defined by
> $$
> T((v_1, \ldots, v_n)) = (v_1 + v_2, v_2 + v_3, \ldots, v_{n-1} + v_2, v_n + v_1). 
> $$
> Find the dimension of the kernel and image of $T$.

I tried a few cases before attempting to prove this. If $n = 1$, the kernel is trivial. When $n = 2$, a vector in the kernel $v = (v_1, v_2)$ have to satisfy $v_1 + v_2 = 0$ and $v_2 + v_1 = 0$. So these take the form $v = (k, -k)$ and the kernel has dimension $1$. When $n = 3$, a vector $v = (v_1, v_2, v_3)$ is in the kernel provided that it satisfies $v_1 = - v_2$, $v_2 = - v_3$, $v_3 = - v_1$. Then $v_1 = - v_2 = v_3 = - v_1$. So $v_1 = - v_1$ and therefore $v_1 = 0$. Then $v_2 = v_3 = 0$, so the kernel is trivial. Next I'll try $n = 4$. A vector $v = (v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4)$ is in the kernel if $v_1 = - v_2$, $v_2 = - v_3$, $v_3 = - v_4$, $v_4 = - v_1$. So $v_1 = - v_2 = v_3 = - v_4$. So $v = (k,-k,k,-k)$ so the kernel has dimension $1$.

The sense I'm getting is that the kernel is trivial if $n$ is odd and $1$ if $n$ is even. After I get the dimension of the kernel, I can use the rank-nullity theorem to find the dimension of the image. Here's my attempt to find the dimensions of the kernel and image, breaking into odd and even cases.

> Let $n$ be odd and $v = (v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ be an element of the kernel. Then
> $$
> T((v_1, \ldots, v_n)) = (v_1 + v_2, v_2 + v_3, \ldots, v_{n-1} + v_2, v_n + v_1) = (0, 0, \ldots, 0, 0). 
> $$
> So
> \begin{align*}
> v_1 + v_2 &= 0 \implies v_1 = - v_2 \\
> v_2 + v_3 &= 0 \implies - v_2 = v_3 \\
> \ldots \\ 
> v_n + v_1 &= 0 \implies v_n = - v_1.
> \end{align*}
> I can iteratively write every component of the vector in terms of $v_1$, and the sign alternates each time.
> $$
> v_1 = - v_2 = v_3 = - v_4 = \ldots = - v_{n-1} = v_n.
> $$
> The last equation says that $v_n = - v_1$, so $v_1 = - v_1$ and $v_1 = \ldots = v_n = 0$. The kernel then has dimension $0$ so the image has dimension $n$.
>
> If $n$ is even, then
> $$
> v_1 = - v_2 = v_3 = - v_4 = \ldots = v_{n-1} = - v_n. 
> $$
> As $-v_n = v_1$, there is no contradiction here. After knowing $v_1$, we know the entire vector, so the vector has the form $(k,-k,k,-k, \ldots, -k)$. The dimension of the kernel is $1$, so the dimension of the image is $n-1$.

I would greatly appreciate any feedback on my attempt at this problem.

Comment: There might be some issues with the $(n-1)th$ coordinate of the image of $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ under $T$. It is probably $v_{n-1}+v_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The odd case is good. I wouldn't change anything there. However, I take some very minor exception to the even case. While the conclusion is correct, the presentation of the proof has some small weaknesses. It's nothing that I'd mark you down for, but if you're seeking guidance, I might as well bring it up.

> As $−v_n=v_1$, there is no contradiction here.

There was no contradiction anywhere, including in the odd case. The odd case had a solution:
$$(v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n) = (0, 0, \ldots, 0).$$
A contradiction suggests that there will be no solutions, and an empty kernel, which is simply not possible with a linear map. It would be better to say something like,

> Note that $-v_n = v_1$ does not restrict the solution set further.

Even then, we are only pointing out that we have a redundant piece of information. We can't technically conclude much from this. I agree that all the solutions must be of the form $(k, -k, k, -k , \ldots, k, -k)$ from the fact that $v_1 = -v_2 = v_3 = \ldots = -v_n$. That is, I believe we have established that:
$$\operatorname{Ker} T \subseteq \{(k, -k, k, -k, \ldots, k, -k) \in \Bbb{R}^n : k \in \Bbb{R}\}.$$
The fact that the last equation $-v_n = v_1$ is redundant does not imply we have equality. To establish this properly, you'd need to show that, for any $k \in \Bbb{R}$,
$$T(k, -k, k, -k ,\ldots, k, -k) = (0, 0, \ldots, 0).$$
I would personally just claim this in the proof, but you could write something like,
\begin{align}
T(k, -k, k, -k ,\ldots, k, -k) &= (k + (-k), -k + k, \ldots, k + (-k), -k + k) \\
&= (0, 0, \ldots, 0).
\end{align}
Thus, we also get $\supseteq$, not just $\subseteq$.