# Kernel and image of linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I am trying to find the dimension of the kernel and image of the linear $T: F^n \to F^n$ defined by
$$
T(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = (x_1 + x_n, x_2 + x_{n-1}, \ldots, x_n + x_1).
$$
My attempt is as follows.

> Let $n$ be even. If $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is in the kernel of $T$,
> \begin{align*}
> (0, \ldots, 0) =T(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (x_1 + x_n, \ldots, x_{n/2} + x_{n/2 + 1}, \ldots, x_n + x_1).
> \end{align*}
> So
> $$\begin{cases}
> x_1 = - x_n, x_2 = - x_{n-1}, \ldots, x_{\frac{n}{2}} = - x_{\frac{n}{2} + 1}
> \end{cases}
> $$
> and the dimension of the kernel is $\frac{n}{2}$, since after the first $\frac{n}{2}$ components are determined, the entire vector is determined. So the dimension of the kernel is $\frac{n}{2}$. By the rank nullity theorem, the dimension of the kernel is also $\frac{n}{2}$.
>
> Let $n$ be odd. Then an element of the kernel has a "middle" term, which is $2 x_{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor + 1}$, so $x_{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} = 0$. If $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is in the kernel of $T$,
> \begin{align*}
> (0, \ldots, 0) =T(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (x_1 + x_n, \ldots, x_{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor + 1} + x_{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor + 1}, \ldots, x_n + x_1).
> \end{align*}
> So
> $$
> x_1 = -x_n, x_2 = -x_{n-1}, \ldots, x_{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor - 1}, x_{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor + 1} = 0, 
> $$
> So there are exactly $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ basis vectors for the dimension of the kernel. The dimension of the image is then $n - \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$.

How does this look? Can I say that $n - \lfloor n/2 \rfloor = \lceil n/2 \rceil$? I'm not sure if I can say this in general.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I found that $\{(-1,0,0,1), (0,-1,1,0)\} is a basis for the kernel, which seems to match the general case. Is that right?

Comment: A [question like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4774253/finding-the-dimension-and-kernel-of-a-linear-map/) was asked not too long ago. Make sure to double-check the odd case; does it really hold true for, say, $n = 3$?

Comment: Also, if you wish to prove $n - \lfloor n/2 \rfloor = \lceil n/2 \rceil$, try breaking it into the odd case and the even case.